# Two different collapsible menus in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two different collapsible menus in mobile version. One for Global Regions and another for default top navigation. 
If globe icon is clicked showing regions as menu
if menu icon is clicked showing menus links.

My Requirement is if user clicks on globe icon the regions are expanded. Now if user click on menu icon, region show be collapsed and menu links should expand. Same for vice versa.

Please advise how we can achieve this in Bootstrap3 .

Comment: can you please make an JS fiddle and show what you trying to do then we can help easily

Comment: Here is the code
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=fHvbfrSS1R

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Hope this may helpful

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/uKfL3mWdAI)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" onclick="$('#bs-example-navbar-collapse-2').collapse('hide');">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"> <a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#f1" data-parent="#accordion">Link1</a></li>
        <li> <a class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#f2" data-parent="#accordion">Link2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>


<section class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse" id="f1">
                <p>Stuff 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="row panel-collapse collapse " id="f2">
                <p>Stuff 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Somehow its not working. I have single nav bar. It contains two different link. Those two links should have different menus and should be collapsible.

Comment: If your issue solved means pls tick my answer Monica

Comment: I ticked your answer. Thanks Jake :)